# Why can't use function of arguments in the different browsers?

Tags: javascript

I want to know why the results of running the following code in the different browsers have differents?

```
(function () {
   //will alert 1, 2, 3 in IE 9, Firefox 8+, Chrome 15,
   // Opera 11 but not in IE 7, 8 and Safari 5
    for (var a in arguments) 
        alert(arguments[a]);
})(1,2,3);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the browsers have different implementations of the arguments object. For a cross browser method use the length property instead.

```
(function () {
        for (var i=0, nLength = arguments.length; i < nLength; i++) {
            alert(arguments[i]);
        }
    })(1,2,3);
```

Comment: Also as a general rule you should never use 'for var i in' when you can use a regular for loop.

Comment: Rats. You were quicker than me. :)

Comment: @PeterWilkinson - The advice is that you shouldn't use a `for/in` loop for iterating the items of an array.  It's perfectly fine to use it for iterating properties on an object (in fact, it's the recommended way to do that).  In this case `arguments` is a pseudo-array so you should use the array method of iterating.

Comment: @jfriend for/in is the recommended way of iterating over object properties? What's the non-recommended way? I said never use for/in when you can use a regular loop. Iterating through object properties is a case where you cannot use a regular for loop.

Comment: @PeterWilkinson - the recommended way of iterating an array is `for (var i=0; i < obj.length; i++)`.  The recommended way of iterating object properties is `for (var i in obj) {if obj.hasOwnProperty(i) {/* do whatever */}}`.

Answer (score 0):

The `arguments` object is actually not an array, though it behaves like one in some ways. It's a special object that lacks most of a JavaScript `array`'s methods by default (though you could apply these methods manually using `apply()`), and includes a `length` property.

In order to access the arguments themselves, just iterate over the `arguments` object with a standard `for` loop. JavaScript's `for-in` statement works over the contents of `array`s, with some critical exceptions, but not this *array-like* structure.

```
for (var i = 0, numArgs = arguments.length; i < numArgs; i++) {
    console.log( arguments[i] );
}
```

Hope that helps!